# cannot call main class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, program-entry-point

I am using this command to run my job on spark.

```
spark-submit --class=ueba.Main    --jars $JARS1,$JARS2  target/UEBA-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar "hdfs://some_location:9000/seco"
```

here is a snap shot of my current project structure. 
[image: Current project structure]

I notice that my old project had this structure, where the main class was under the folder 'scala'. i thnk the folder 'scala' was automatically created when I cretaed my old project. In my current project, I do not have a (blue) folder 'scala'.

[image: old project structure]

questions:

1. how do i call my main class?
2. can you explain me what is the blue folder scala? why do i need it? i only have a blue box java.

> EDIT

This is my new structure. I make the 'blue' folder scala (turns out that blue folders indicate project root). Now 'scala' is the project root.But  I dont think the path to my main class is correct. i try to run this command and it says 'class not found exeption' (I ran mvn package behore hand to get a jar)

```
spark-submit --class ueba.Main    --jars $JARS1,$JARS2  target/UEBA-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar "hdfs://some_path:9000/seco"
```

[image: updated project structure]

question: what is the correct command w.r.t. the location of the main class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a scala sources root directory in Intellij IDEA:

1. Add a scala folder.
2. Right click that folder and select "Mark Directory as" > "Sources Root".
3. Add the same package structure, "ueba" in your case and put your .scala files there.

Comment: yes it worked. pls tell me what command to use to run my main class. thank you.

Comment: Make a JAR using maven or sbt then use: **spark-submit --class=<your-fully-qualified-main-class>.class --master <you-master> <your-jar>.jar**

Comment: sorry ... what the path to my main class not that 'scala' folder is source root? is it ueba.Main?

Comment: Yes, it will be ueba.Main scala is the root folder for all your sources all the packages reside there. A class will always be accessed by the package it is in and not the directory. You never do usr.local.SomeProject.src.main.scala.Main.class :D